# DetailsList filter office ui fabric

Tags: typescript, office365

I would like to filter my office ui fabric detailslist. I would like to have the filter on all the columns in the list.

the information in the list is coming from Office365 with custom api in between.

I tried to use a text box to filter but it didn't work. Or is there any possibility that you can filter like in office365? The code I'm using at this moment is included below. The code using for sorting I let out. This is working without any problems.

```
export interface Basics {
  key: number;
  name: string;
}

export interface MyState{
  requestListItems: any[];
  columns: IColumn [];
}
class Requests extends Component<any, MyState>{
  private _allItems: Basics[];
  constructor(props:{}) {
    super(props);
    const columns: IColumn[] = [{
      key:'Title',
      name:'Title',
      fieldName:'Title',
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Request_type',
      name:'Request type',
      fieldName:'Request_type',
      minWidth:150,
      maxWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Request_template',
      name:'Template',
      fieldName:'Request_template',
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Version',
      name:'Version', 
      fieldName:'Version', 
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Request_status',
      name:'Request status', 
      fieldName:'Request_status', 
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Request_destination_url',
      name:'Request destination url', 
      fieldName:'Request_destination_url', 
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    },
    {
      key:'Request_details',
      name:'Request details', 
      fieldName:'Request_details', 
      maxWidth:150,
      minWidth:150,
      isSorted: true,
      isSortedDescending:false,
      sortAscendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted A to Z',
      sortDescendingAriaLabel: 'Sorted Z to A',
      onColumnClick: this._onColumnClick
    }
  ];
  this.state = {
      requestListItems:[{
          Title: '',
          requestType: '',
          template:'',
          version:'',
          requestStatus:'',
          destinationUrl:'',
          details:''
        }
      ],
      columns:columns
    };

    this._allItems = [];
}  
componentDidMount() {  
  // Custom function to retrieve the list info  
  this.GetRequestList();  
}  

GetRequestList(){  
  var reactHandler = this;  
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  request.open('GET', '.../api/requests/getRequests/all', true);  
  request.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");  
  //this callback gets called when the server responds to the ajax call  
  request.onreadystatechange = function(){  
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200){  
          var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);  
          console.log("Result data: " + result.Data);
          console.log("Result data length: " + result.Data.length);
          reactHandler.setState({  
            requestListItems: result.Data  
          });   

      }  
      else if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status !== 200){  
          console.log('Error in retrieving data!');  
      }  
  }; 
  request.send();  
} 

public render() {
  let column = this.state.columns;
  let RequestItems: any[];
  RequestItems =[""];
  this.state.requestListItems.map((requests,key) =>{
        RequestItems = [{Title: requests.title, 
          Request_type: requests.requestType, 
          Version: requests.version, 
          Request_template: requests.template, 
          Request_status: requests.requestStatus, 
          Request_destination_url: requests.destinationUrl, 
          Request_details: requests.details}]
  }) 
    return (
                <div className="ms-Grid-col ms-sm6 ms-md8 ms-lg10"><h1>REQUESTS</h1>
                <p>
                <TextField label="Filter by title:" onChange={this._onFilter}/>
                </p>
                  <p>
                  <DetailsList items={RequestItems} columns={column}/>
                  </p>
                </div>        );

  }
  private _onFilter = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue?: string): void => {
    this.setState({
      requestListItems: newValue ? this._allItems.filter(i => i.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(newValue) > -1) : this._allItems
    });
  };

export default Requests;
```